Is there any way I jump the code to the same word
I'm looking for extension or way to jumping to the same word in my code.
For Example: File A and B place the same folder
File A: #define ABC = 20
File B: MyAge = ABC;
I would like to "Ctrl+left click" on ABC in the File B to jumpped my cursor to ABC in the File A.
And, when I press "Ctrl+P" to go back to the previous line (File A)
I don't know my request is possible?
I try to find the extension in VSCode, but I still not found yet.

Possibly relevant: How can I navigate back to the last cursor position in Visual Studio Code?

Try "Alt" + 'G' + left mouse click

Ctrl+left click already works as you described if you use the C/C++ extension (assuming file B includes A). And going back is alt+left by default.
